# html5 video parametrized source

Tags: html, video

Hello
I have this html video tag:

```
<video id="asdasd" width="320" height="240" controls preload>
    <source src="getVideo.php?video=some.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Where getVideo.php is:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($drivepath.$_GET['video']);
?>
```

I tried this on chrome and safari and it works, but it doesn't work on ipad.
How can I make work this on ipad? Is there a way to make video src parametrized, without giving the file path directly?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably the encoding of the MP4. (Hard to say with authority without a link to your problem file.)  Apple devices are very particular about what they will and will not play.

**The solution:** Encode the video with h264 Baseline Profile 3.0

Technically the iPad can support h264 Main Profile 3.1, but that won't cover iPhones.